# Can I use python's mouse library with Spyder 5.2.2 @ Anaconda 2.3.1

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I'm trying to learn how to control the mouse with Python learning from:

[How to Control your Mouse in Python](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/control-mouse-python)

My IDE is Spyder (version 5.2.2) and I'm running it from Anaconda (version 2.3.1).

When I try to execute:

> conda install mouse

I get the following error:

> The following packages are not available from current channels: - mouse

(Full error description below).

I'm new to Anaconda/Spyder/Python so I'm sorry If that's a newbie question, but can I somehow use the mouse library at my environment? If yes, what's the catch? If no, what's the alternative?

Thank you.

Full error description after running "conda install mouse":

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: mouse
Current channels:
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're looking for, navigate to https://anaconda.org and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues also following this post. I used the following:

```
conda install pip
pip install mouse
```

After doing so restart the kernel and `import mouse` should be working.

Comment: and of course, best do it inside an venv after:  python -m venv myenv